# Measuring influence in lme4

Tags: r, statistics, modeling, mixed-models

I am currently doing mixed effects model analysis for a university project.
I am currently trying to measure potential influences in my data using the following and become stuck with this error message in R.

```
alt.est.S <- influence(Smdl1,"subject")

Error in get(as.character(model@call)[3]) : object 'FALSE' not found.
```

My model is as follows:

```
Smdl1 <- lmer(midpoint~season+(1|subject),REML="FALSE")
```

Is there anything obvious here that stands out as reasoning for this error message? Any feedback would be really appreciated.

Comment: I fit the model `mod <- lmer(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length + (1|Species), iris, REML = FALSE)`, which has the same basic structure as yours does. the `influence()` function worked fine for me. I would assume that the error you're getting has something to do with your data, but I can't check unless you post the dataset.

Comment: can you let us know `packageVersion("lme4")` please?

Comment: I had to upgrade `lme4` to get the `iris` example above to work. `install.packages("lme4")`

Comment: the lme4 package version is 1.1.19

Comment: I have just added "iris" into my model description and now produce a new error using influence() of:                                                                                           "Error in model@flist[[group]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2"                            I guess this would imply there is an issue with my dataset?